# Using SLP (service location protocol) in an environment without multicast (OpenSLP)

Tags: networking

Is it possible to use SLP (service location protocol) in an environment which does not support multicasts but just broadcasts? From what I've read it should be possible, but I can't get it to work.

Let's say I have a very simple little network with just a couple of computers attached to an unmanaged switch. So there is no router which could handle multicast group tables.

When using OpenSLP, the server side (the windows servcie which implements a SLP SA (service agent)) has an option which forces it to use broadcast instead of multicast. So far so good. But how can I tell OpenSLP to use broadcasts on the UA (user agent) side (when calling SLPFindSrvs, for example)?

All I want to do is a little test in that network where on one computer (where slpd is running as a windows service) I register a service using

```
slptool register service:myserv.x://myhost.com
```

And on an other computer I want to find that service using

```
slptool findsrvs service:myserv.x
```

But no services are found...

Comment: Btw, it would be nice to have a SLP tag here. But I can't create any new tags yet.

Comment: Ask and you shall receive. An SLP tag seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Roel from the OpenSLP newsgroup I found the solution. It was not a network problem but a problem of misusing `slptool`. Here is what Roel wrote:

> With the default settings, a registration will automatically be removed 
>   a few seconds after the process disappeared that made the registration. 
>   This is to prevent keeping 'dangling' registrations from processes that 
>   didn't properly deregister.
>
> In case you use 'slptool register' the process making the registration 
>   is 'slptool', which immediately exits. The registration is therefore 
>   automatically removed a few seconds afterwards.
>
> Try using a configuration file with 'net.slp.watchRegistrationPID = false'.

Unfortunately this setting is not documented and there is no hint in the usage notes of `slptool`...

So to answer my question: Yes, it's possible to run SLP (OpenSLP) in a network without a multicast router.